# How to test interval inclusion $x\in [a,b)$ with a single comparison?

Tags: calculus

The simplest test if $x\in [a,b)$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$. 
is to check $$x\in [a,b)\Leftrightarrow x\ge a \text{ and } x<b.$$

Now my question is, if I allow functions made up form the operations $+$, $-$, $*$ and $/$, there is thera a way to avoid two comparisons to achieve the interval inclusion test.

**Question**: are there functions $f(a,b, x)$ and $g(a,b, x)$ made up from the operations $+$, $-$, $*$ and $/$ such that
$$x\in [a,b) \Leftrightarrow g(a,b,x) \ge f(a,b, x)$$

Or otherwise how could I show that there are not?

---

Edit: If both ends are closed there is such a function: $$f(x)=(b−x)(x−a)\ge 0 \Rightarrow x\in[a,b]$$

---

Edit: Background: I was discussing with a fellow programmer if very fast numerical operations could improve boolean interval checks.

Comment: Only in the unbounded case $(b = \infty)$ with $f(a,  b) = a$.

Comment: @SammyBlack You are right, I will edit the question.

Comment: Any $x \ge a ge f(a,b)$ would verify $x \in [a,b)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can establish the bounds with a single inequality involving a function of $x$.  Consider the rational function 
$$
f(x) = - \frac{x - a}{(x - b)^3}.
$$

Then, you have
$$
x \in [a, b) \qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad  f(x) \ge 0.
$$

Comment: Question, why the cube? I mean, doesn't $$f(x) =  \frac{a-x}{(x - b)}.$$ work as well?

Comment: @Raphael that was for a different question. I mistagged. Ignore. It is the fractional part of x btw.

Comment: Yes.  I wanted the denominator to have higher degree so that $x$-axis would be a horizontal asymptote, but that's not necessary.

Comment: But for this to work I need the additional test that $x\neq b$, right?

Comment: @Raphael yes. For instance, $f(x)=(b-x)(x-a) \ge 0 \implies x \in [a,b]$

Comment: And $f(x)\gt 0 \implies x \in (a,b)$ You can either do open-open intervals or closed-closed intervals. I don't think you can mix them.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Ok, in that case the question is still open.

Comment: @Raphael But that depends on how strict your rules are, for instance in Sammy's suggestion, at $x=b$, $f(x)$ is undefined, so you don't need to test $x\ne b$ if you get a value for $f(x)$. I think context might help though, why do you *need* this?

Comment: @Sabyasachi thanks for your comments. I have added the information to the question. The background is a discussion I had about interval inclusion tests in a computer program. The progamm will crash if $x=b$, therefore I need to test.

Comment: @Raphael boolean checks themselves are very fast though. Will be interesting if someone comes up with something. Also the program need not crash given appropriate exception handling.Divide by zero is a common exception.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Admitted, on current hardware it's a hypothetical question. Exception handling requires at least one comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there were, then $x \in [a,b) \Leftrightarrow x \geq f(a,b) \Leftrightarrow x \in [f(a,b), +\infty)$. Therefore $[a,b) = [f(a,b), +\infty)$. Contradiction. I'm not sure what you expected?

Comment: The question was ill posed, I should have been $f(a,b,x)$. I have fixed the question.